# Automatically create listview items with an anchor tag in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am making a webapp with Jquery Mobile. I got my data back from a webservice function.
Now to get this data in my web page I am using a ajax call.

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function () {
var userId =  $("#userId").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "~SYSTEM.URL~~CAMPAIGN.URL~/SelligentMobile/Webservice/WebService.asmx/getNieuwtjes",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'userId':'" + userId + "'}",
            success: function (response) {       
            var nieuwtjes = response.d;
              if (nieuwtjes.length > 0) {   
                        $.each(nieuwtjes, function (i, entity) {
                    $('#nieuwtjesList').append(
                            //Here come's the data from web function         
                  });
            } 
        }        
      });
});
```

Now in #nieuwtjesList should come all the data that I get back from the server. These data is a newsTopic. And it should show it like this.

```
<li><a href="~PROBE(239)~">~ITEM.ONDERWERP~ </a></li>
```

My question is, how can I create the line above for every record I got back from my webservice function.

Kind Regards.

Stef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to create the HTML to append for each line

```
$("<li/>").append($("<a/>")
    .attr("href", <HREF FROM YOUR DATA>)
    .text(<TEXT FROM YOUR DATA>)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) to easily implement this.

Comment: This library looks great but it's still in beta and the usecase here is dead simple stupid ;=)

Comment: It will probably never come out of beta but I've had no problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nieuwtjes = response.d;
          if (nieuwtjes.length > 0) {   
                    var html ='';
                    $.each(nieuwtjes, function (i, entity) {
                     html += '<li><a href="'+ _urs_href_data+'">'+ i.ONODERWERP+'</a></li>';
                   });

                $('#nieuwtjesList').append($(html));
        }
```